# Integrated Graphics Controller is not listed in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: drivers, graphics, intel-graphics, amd-graphics

`lspci | grep VGA` gives me

```
lspci | grep VGA
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Park [Mobility Radeon HD 5430/5450/5470]
```

It's not listing Intel HD graphics driver. I want to try hybrid graphics

- Laptop: Dell Inspiron
- Ubuntu: 14.04

Answer (score -1):

The intel-linux-graphics-driver is probably the easiest way to install the correct intel linux graphics driver. This package is provided by intel's [Open Source Technology Center](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/)

To summarize thier [instructions](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/2014/intelr-graphics-installer-linux-1.0.7):

1. Download the latest deb file from the [downloads](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads) page.  The latest installer, [intel-graphics-installer-linux-1.0.7](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/2014/intelr-graphics-installer-linux-1.0.7) should work for Ubuntu 14.04. Install this package using:
   `sudo dpkg -i intel-linux-graphics-installer_1.0.7-0intel1_amd64.deb`
2. In order to "trust" the Intel® Graphics Installer for Linux*, you will need to add keys to Ubuntu's software package manager ("apt"). Open a terminal, and execute these line:

`wget --no-check-certificate https://download.01.org/gfx/RPM-GPG-KEY-ilg -O - | \
sudo apt-key add -`

`wget --no-check-certificate https://download.01.org/gfx/RPM-GPG-KEY-ilg-2 -O - | \
sudo apt-key add -`

3. Once installed, you can find the Intel Graphics Installer for Linux* in your application dashboard. Just look for our logo, or begin typing 'Intel'. If you are a power user, you can open a terminal and execute: `intel-linux-graphics-installer`

Not sure which [Dell Inspiron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dell_Inspiron) you are using, but I believe that my solution should work for all of them.